# How can I hide a paragraph of information in Google Docs?

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs

I want to hide a blob of information or a paragraph.

I identified two ways to try this neither of which worked.

One was to store it in a **comment** which takes it outside the page but I can't use because it puts it on the side of the page.

The other way to store it in a **link**.  However this does not work as the link adder wants a valid URL.

Is there another way to do this I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using the script editor?

Comment: 1/2 works as I can hide information but it is not liked or related to any text like comments and links.  It is just linked to the whole page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the script editor to store hidden information.  You can use comments `/* */` to hold the actual information.

Make sure and click save when you are done.

Comment: Could you explain how this works? The only script editor in Docs I can find, is behind `Extensions > Apps Script`, but this opens a script editor in a new tab. I don't know how to insert any script in the document itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Option_1**

Yes. Simple but *not secure*.

Change the color of the paragraph to white.

[image]

Then you can use a simple search to find the hidden areas (in this case they are preceeded of # symbol, as if they were comments in code)

[image]

Note: If anyone does a 'select all' they will see the hidden text, so the usability is very limited.

**Option_2**

Another way, a bit more convoluted, is to link paragraphs to cells in a google sheets document (let's call it Document_A). If on Document_A you delete the cells the Doc is referencing and update on Doc, the content is gone.

I hope the video is clearer.
[image]

To created linked content (extremely easy), just copy the cells, and paste on the Doc. A pop-up will ask you if you want to link the content. Answer Yes.